# Use of ANCOVA With two group Pre/Post and an Ordinal DV

Tags: ordinal-data, ancova

Say I have a two group pre test / post test design. 
The IV is attendance or non attendance at an educational course. 
The DV is ordinal from 0 - 5 / Strongly Agree - Strongly Disagree

I have been reading about the benefits of ANCOVA - would it's use be appropriate here and if not, what would be?

Answer (score 1):

An ANCOVA is simply a multiple regression with no interaction term between the IV and the covariate. You can perform a [proportional odds regression](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/node/176) given your ordinal outcome.

The ANCOVA is useful if there is balance on the pre-test across both groups and/or you have random assignment to both groups. See Knapp & Schafer (2009) for further discussion of this. Also, Miller and Chapman (2001) provide a very good discussion of ANCOVA.

Knapp, T. R., & Schafer, W. D. (2009). From Gain Score t to ANCOVA F (and vice versa). *Practical Assessment, Research & Evaluation, 14*(6). Retrieved from pareonline.net/getvn.asp?v=14&n=6

Miller, G. A., & Chapman, J. P. (2001). Misunderstanding analysis of covariance. *Journal of Abnormal Psychology, 110*(1), 40–48. https://doi.org/10.1037/0021-843X.110.1.40